# How to foreach php array to create new element with simpledom find

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im trying to replace 'richtext' element in html page with a content(summary) i have with [simpledom html]:(https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm)

an array variable 'summary' with ["sentences"]=> sentence1 and sentence2 and so on

I tried

```php
  foreach ($summary->sentences as $sentence) {

        $outhtml->find('div[class=richtext]',index)->outertext='<p>'.$sentence.'</p>';
index++;

    }
```

This save the last element from array into html

```php
  foreach ($summary->sentences as $sentence) {

        $outhtml->find('div[class=richtext]',0)->outertext='<p>'.$sentence.'</p>';

    }
```

Expected result

```html
<div class='richtext'>
<p>sentence 1</p>
<p>sentence 2</p>
<p>sentence 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean, _“This only save the last from array”_ …? Please go read [ask] and [mre], and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: it create the last element from array, i wanted it to create new elements for all in 'summary' array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a loop (which can easily overwrite the previous text), you can use `implode()` to build up the content and then set the inner text from that...

```
$html->find('div[class=richtext]',0)->innertext = "<p>".
             implode("</p><p>", $summary->sentences).
             "</p>";
```